# Assign status in status window json(game) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this problem for weeks, I'm making some kind of game and it seems I cannot assign status on it(I'm using json since I'm having a hard time learning database)

Example of the json file:

```
{
 "199037683676":
   {
     "name": "Carl",
     "Health": "100",
     "Defense": "1",
     "Strength": "1",
     "SP": "10"
   }
}
```

I want to assign the SP to statuses deduct the SP that assign to statuses and add that to status that been assign. But it seems like I can't.

Example:
/// parse already define

```
let name = "Health";
let value = "3";
let status = statuses[name];

status += value

/// and stringfy and write.
```

Comment: Okay can you provide the output you got? Is it because your JSON doesn't contain _actual numbers_ but _strings_? Which means if you do `+` it will result in another string? If it's not that this question is a bit unclear... Oh wait, I see it now. You are not adjusting the actual key in your JSON object, you are just modifying the contents of a variable. Tht will not be reflected in your JSON, because numbers and strings are constants.

Comment: Where is `statuses` coming from? You have data which is an object containing one key/value pair. The key is `199037683676` and its associated value is another object with properties like `health` and `SP`. At no point in your code are you accessing that nested object with the key so it makes your question unclear and difficult to understand? Are you asking how to change the values in the nested object?

Comment: The output is working fine, but it doesn't save like the SP

Comment: After the user registered the json will automatically created with statuses as default

Answer (score 0):

You have values as strings inside your object, but you want to treat them as strings. A solution is to operate only with numbers:

```js
let input = `{
 "199037683676":
   {
     "name": "Carl",
     "Health": "100",
     "Defense": "1",
     "Strength": "1",
     "SP": "10"
   }
}`;
{ //first test, result is 1003
    let statuses = JSON.parse(input)["199037683676"];
    let name = "Health";
    let value = "3";
    let status = statuses[name];

    status += value;
    console.log(status);
}
{ //first test, result is 1003
    let statuses = JSON.parse(input)["199037683676"];
    let name = "Health";
    let value = 3;
    let status = parseInt(statuses[name]);

    status += value;
    console.log(status);
}
```

The `+` operator is concatenation rather than arithmetic addition when at least an operand is a string. Proof:

```js
console.log([
    "2" + "2",
    "2" + 2,
    2 + "2",
    2 + 2
]);
```

You see the result of adding 2 + 2 being "22" whenever at least one of them are strings and 4 if and only if both are numeric.

Alternatively you can make sure that health will be numeric inside your JSON, so you will not need to parse it into a number:

```js
    let input = `{
     "199037683676":
       {
         "name": "Carl",
         "Health": 100,
         "Defense": "1",
         "Strength": "1",
         "SP": "10"
       }
    }`;
        let statuses = JSON.parse(input)["199037683676"];
        let name = "Health";
        let value = 3;
        let status = statuses[name];

        status += value;
        console.log(status);
```